# How to add product name in email template prestashop?

Tags: email, prestashop, product

How can I add a product name in an email template sent to clients in prestashop? Something like {product_name}?

Comment: Explain more. where you want to add this? do you work on custom module or default emails?

Comment: I want to add a list of products to the sent email after changing the status. By adding the {products} parameter to the email template, the products are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `sendEmail` method in `classes/order/OrderHistory`.

You need to get products there and assign into `{products}` variable, you can find proper example of how to do this in:
`classes/PaymentModule.php` in `validateOrder` method.